# Xamarin Android installation fails

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to install Xamarin for Android and I'm having a really weird issue and I can't find any help anywhere. 
Once the installation starts and I click on Next button in the screen with the answer about if I want to collect information, it doesn't do anything. Checking the log file it always cancel the installation due to an internal error, I will copy the log section that's giving me the information:

```
[287C:256C][2013-01-13T14:02:06]: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\MAXIPO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{e9ab888e-6304-4ba3-b36a-b1a350d36592}\.be\XamarinSetup.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{e9ab888e-6304-4ba3-b36a-b1a350d36592}\XamarinSetup.exe'
[287C:256C][2013-01-13T14:02:07]: Registering bundle dependency provider: {e9ab888e-6304-4ba3-b36a-b1a350d36592}, version: 3.0.0.0
[2464:19E4][2013-01-13T14:02:07]: Prompt for source of container: WixAttachedContainer, path: C:\Soft\Android\XamarinSetup.exe
[2464:19E4][2013-01-13T14:02:07]: Failed to resolve source for file: C:\Soft\Android\XamarinSetup.exe, error: 0x80070642.
[2464:19E4][2013-01-13T14:02:07]: Error 0x80070642: Failed while prompting for source (original path 'C:\Soft\Android\XamarinSetup.exe').
[2464:19E4][2013-01-13T14:02:07]: Failed to acquire container: WixAttachedContainer to working path: C:\Users\MAXIPO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{e9ab888e-6304-4ba3-b36a-b1a350d36592}\4675EB82A6A7F3C48F80571AB6E8495BD1C803BA, error: 0x80070642.
[2464:2930][2013-01-13T14:02:07]: Error 0x80070642: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
```

Failed to resolve source for file : XamarinSetup.exe. This file doesn't exist ever, I've never found it even refreshing the folder over and over during installation in case it's deleted during the process. I can see it starts copying files into the temp folder, and suddenly all of them dissapear (I'm sure due to the cancellation). I'm running it in Windows 7, any idea? I've been looking for a solution for days even changing permissions in my system, giving access to guest, my user, administrator, and so worth to all the paths just in case.

Regards.

Answer (score 14):

Despite of the problem itself I could finally install everything. Thanks to the Xamarin support I knew the automatic installation doesn't work always, so it's much better to install every package manually. So the instructions they gave me are the following ones:

It looks like a manual installation would get the trial version of Mono for Android installed. Please follow the below instructions:
Please download and install packages shown below in the order listed:

1. JDK 1.6: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u31-download-1501634.html
   Please choose the jdk-6u31-windows-i586.exe installer from the list above.
2. Android SDK: http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r20-windows.exe
   After the main installer is done, please open the SDK Manager and install the following platform APIs: 7,8,10,12,14
3. GTK#: http://download.xamarin.com/Installer/gtk-sharp-2.12.10.win32.msi
4. MonoDevelop: http://download.xamarin.com/monodevelop/Windows/MonoDevelop-3.0.5.msi
5. Mono for Android SDK: http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Windows/mono-android-4.4.55.104956787.msi

You can skip steps 3 and 4 if you don't need/want to use MonoDevelop and use VisualStudio (2010 Professional or better) instead. In that case you must have VS installed before proceeding with step 5.

Always keep in mind to install the API's in the step 2, also JDK 1.6 is not the last one anymore so it will prompt you to install 1.7 instead of this one.