# Why Xamarin Workload on Visual Studio 2022 Community AND MAUI Workload on VS Community Pre-Release is not installing?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, installation, xamarin.android

Why Xamarin Workload on VS 2022 Community is not installing ?

I have been using Visual Studio Community 2022 and I added Xamarin workload but, at each attempt I keep running into following warning:
[Error on VS 2022 Community](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB9MX.png)

This is the error on VS Community 2022 Pre-Release
[Error on VS 2022 Community Pre-Release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJUmi.png)

Both the errors state, Something went wrong with the install.

**Logs from VS Community 2022 Pre-release**

You can troubleshoot the package failures by:

```
1. Search for solutions using the search URL below for each package failure
2. Modify your selections for the affected workloads or components and then retry the installation
3. Remove the product from your machine and then install again
```

If the issue has already been reported on the Developer Community, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, we encourage you to create a new issue so that other developers will be able to find solutions or workarounds. You can create a new issue from within the Visual Studio Installer in the upper-right hand corner using the "Provide feedback" button.

================================================================================

Package 'AndroidBuildTools_Xamarin,version=30.0.5' failed to install.
Search URL
https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=AndroidBuildTools_Xamarin;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1263094860
Details
Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -Noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat None -Command "& """C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\AndroidBuildTools_Xamarin,version=30.0.5\AndroidSDKPrivateInstall.ps1""" -Package build-tools-30.0.3 -FileName 91936d4ee3ccc839f0addd53c9ebf087b1e39251.build-tools_r30.0.3-windows.zip -Version 30.0.3 -AndroidHome """C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk""" -RequestedAVDs """""" -Operation Install; exit $LastExitCode"
Return code: 1263094860
Return code details: Unknown error (0x4b494c4c)
Log
C:\Users\maya\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20220626164126_452_AndroidBuildTools_Xamarin.log
Impacted workloads
.NET Multi-platform App UI development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=17.3.32610.5340)
Impacted components
.NET MAUI (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Maui.All,version=17.3.32610.340)
.NET MAUI development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Maui.Shared,version=17.3.32610.340)
.NET MAUI for Android (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Maui.Android,version=17.3.32610.340)
Android SDK setup (API level 31) (Component.Android.SDK.MAUI,version=17.3.32610.340)
Xamarin (Component.Xamarin,version=17.3.32610.340)

**As An Alternative after going through a couple of articles ** I came to know that Xamarin is now available as MAUI under Visual Studio Pre-Release. Therefore, I ended up installing VS 2022 Community Pre-Release, only to find out that it doesn't solve the problem I am facing.
**Logs from VS Community 2022:**

Something went wrong with the install.

You can troubleshoot the package failures by:

```
1. Search for solutions using the search URL below for each package failure
2. Modify your selections for the affected workloads or components and then retry the installation
3. Remove the product from your machine and then install again
```

If the issue has already been reported on the Developer Community, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, we encourage you to create a new issue so that other developers will be able to find solutions or workarounds. You can create a new issue from within the Visual Studio Installer in the upper-right hand corner using the "Provide feedback" button.

================================================================================

Package 'AndroidPlatformTools_Xamarin,version=31.0.5' failed to install.
Search URL
https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=AndroidPlatformTools_Xamarin;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1263094860
Details
Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -Noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat None -Command "& """C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\AndroidPlatformTools_Xamarin,version=31.0.5\AndroidSDKPrivateInstall.ps1""" -Package platform-tools -FileName platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows.zip -Version 31.0.3 -AndroidHome """C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk""" -RequestedAVDs """""" -Operation Install; exit $LastExitCode"
Return code: 1263094860
Return code details: Unknown error (0x4b494c4c)
Log
C:\Users\maya\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20220626161637_001_AndroidPlatformTools_Xamarin.log
Impacted workloads
Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=17.2.32503.295)
Impacted components
Android SDK setup (API level 31) (Component.Android.SDK.MAUI,version=17.2.32408.312)
Xamarin (Component.Xamarin,version=17.2.32408.312)

---

Package 'AndroidTools,version=25.2.5.9' failed to install.
Search URL
https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=AndroidTools;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1263094860
Details
Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -Noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat None -Command "& """C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\AndroidTools,version=25.2.5.9\AndroidSDKPrivateInstall.ps1""" -Package tools -FileName tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip -Version 25.2.5 -AndroidHome """C:\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25""" -RequestedAVDs """""" -Operation Install; exit $LastExitCode"
Return code: 1263094860
Return code details: Unknown error (0x4b494c4c)
Log
C:\Users\maya\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20220626161637_002_AndroidTools.log
Impacted components
Android SDK setup (API level 25) (local install for Mobile development with C++) (Component.Android.SDK25.Private,version=17.2.32408.312)
Google Android Emulator (API Level 25) (local install) (Component.Google.Android.Emulator.API25.Private,version=17.2.32408.312)

After this, I have verified Xamarin Projects are not visible while creating a new project.

I have also gone through the available help on:

[Troubleshoot Visual Studio installation and upgrade issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2022)

[Xamarin Android installation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305951/xamarin-android-installation-fails) on This MAUI Check shows following Error:
[Upon running the commands suggested here to fix the MAUI Android/IOS Workload installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7nki.png)
[Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/xamarin-installation-does-not-work-with-vs-2019-16/1312176)

[Problem installing Android workload for MAUI Visual Studio 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69522872/problem-installing-android-workload-for-maui-visual-studio-2022)

Please suggest if any one of you have had run into this issue:

Comment: There was a [similar case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-install-androidtool-xamarin/604557) and you can check it. In addition, had you tried to reinstall the visual studio not update?

Comment: Yes, I tried to reinstall Visual Studio Community 2022 and Preview a couple of times, but no luck. Let me check the other option you have suggested.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - I had to uninstall the Antivirus on my machine and started with Repair, which solved the problem.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - I did not realize that I left without thanking you for this one. Thank you so much, that really saved me a lot of time.

Comment: All right, I post an answer and this maybe help the people have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

For someone has the same problem:

Close or uninstall the antivirus on the machine and then repair the visual studio.

More information:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-install-androidtool-xamarin/604557